# SPClientTemplates is not defined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I want to customise a list in sharepoint by uploading a javascript file in the JS link in sharepoint. So I wrote the following code.
The purpose of the code is to take the value of the column Nom_x0020_Du_x0020_Projet which is the internal name of the column of the list I want to customise in sharepoint, which is actually a link followed by its description. So the code split the value of an item in that column into an array that have two values: the address and the description.

```
(function(){
      // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render
      var nom_projetContext = {};
      nom_projetContext.Templates = {};
      nom_projetContext.Templates.Fields = {
        //Apply the new redenring for nom du projet field on the list view
        "Nom_x0020_Du_x0020_Projet" : {"View" : nomProjetModifie}
      };
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides( nomProjetModifie);
})();
var adresse;
//this function provides our purpose
function nomProjetModifie(ctx){
  var nomComplet = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

  //slice nomComplet into to substrings
  var arrayOfSubstrings = nomComplet.split(",");
  adresse = arrayOfSubstrings[0];
  var description = arrayOfSubstrings[1];

  return "<span onclcik='redirection()'>"+description+"</span>";
}

function redirection(){
  document.location.href = adresse;
}
```

But no matterwhat I do, I have the same error "SPClientTemplates is not defined". 
How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to resolve the problem.
First we must the following statement:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function(){
    //All our code goes here
})
```

So the final code will be like that for my problem

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function(){
    (function(){
  // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want     to change it's output render
  var nom_projetContext = {};
  nom_projetContext.Templates = {};
  nom_projetContext.Templates.Fields = {
    //Apply the new redenring for nom du projet field on the list view
    "Nom_x0020_Du_x0020_Projet" : {"View" : nomProjetModifie}
  };
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides( nomProjetModifie);
})();
var adresse;
//this function provides our purpose
function nomProjetModifie(ctx){
  var nomComplet = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

  //slice nomComplet into to substrings
  var arrayOfSubstrings = nomComplet.split(",");
  adresse = arrayOfSubstrings[0];
  var description = arrayOfSubstrings[1];

  return "<span onclcik=\'redirection()\'>"+description+"</span>";
}

function redirection(){
  document.location.href = adresse;
}
})
```

It works, and I no long have this error message